# PHP Mortgage Calculator Canada

Tags: php, formula, calculator

I just found a mortgage calculator function:

```
function calculatePayment($price, $down, $term)
{
$loan = $price - $down;
$rate = (2.5/100) / 12;
$month = $term * 12;
$payment = floor(($loan*$rate/(1-pow(1+$rate,(-1*$month))))*100)/100;
return $payment;
}
```

So if I do:

```
calculatePayment(200000,0,25)
```

it return me 897.23$.

The problem is that, if I compare with BMO Bank or duproprio.com calculators, it seem that my function is not exactly working as on the 2 other sites, the result is 895,93$.

Can someone help me figuring out why it doesn't return the good amount?

Thanks alot

Comment: Where did you find this function? Is it taking the compounding into account properly?  Check out this link --I would download the excel spreadsheet at this site and "reverse engineer" the calculations. http://www.yorku.ca/amarshal/mortgage.htm

Comment: I found another website that has the same calculation as you do. I'm guessing there might be a rounding issue because the're only a couple bucks off if you round off to 4 places and they round off to 6 you might be a little bit off.  The Site:

http://www.bankrate.com/calculators/mortgages/mortgage-calculator.aspx?MSA=1010

Comment: any site that gives currency exchange rates can 'slip' a bit; just for a test i pulled the current data from currencyfeed.com and yahoo apis for EUR 1 to USD and the results were:   1.2537, 1.2524.

Answer (score 3):

Ive converted the Balance calculation portion of http://www.secureapp.com/tools/mortgage.html into a PHP function (Also ive added a down payment variable) and given an usage example:

```
$principal = 684000; //Mortgage Amount 
$interest_rate = 2.89; //Interest Rate %
$down = $principal *0.10; //10% down payment
$years = 25;
$months = 0;
$compound = 2; //compound is always set to 2
$frequency = 12; //Number of months (Monthly (12), Semi-Monthly (24), Bi-Weekly(26) and Weekly(52) 

function calcPay($MORTGAGE, $AMORTYEARS, $AMORTMONTHS, $INRATE, $COMPOUND, $FREQ, $DOWN){
$MORTGAGE = $MORTGAGE - $DOWN;
$compound = $COMPOUND/12;
$monTime = ($AMORTYEARS * 12) + (1 * $AMORTMONTHS);
$RATE = ($INRATE*1.0)/100;
$yrRate = $RATE/$COMPOUND;
$rdefine = pow((1.0 + $yrRate),$compound)-1.0;
$PAYMENT = ($MORTGAGE*$rdefine * (pow((1.0 + $rdefine),$monTime))) / ((pow((1.0 + $rdefine),$monTime)) - 1.0);
if($FREQ==12){
    return $PAYMENT;}
if($FREQ==26){
    return $PAYMENT/2.0;}
if($FREQ==52){
    return $PAYMENT/4.0;}
if($FREQ==24){
    $compound2 = $COMPOUND/$FREQ;
    $monTime2 = ($AMORTYEARS * $FREQ) + ($AMORTMONTHS * 2);
    $rdefine2 = pow((1.0 + $yrRate),$compound2)-1.0;
    $PAYMENT2 = ($MORTGAGE*$rdefine2 * (pow((1.0 + $rdefine2),$monTime2)))/  ((pow((1.0 + $rdefine2),$monTime2)) - 1.0);
    return $PAYMENT2;
}
}

$payment = calcPay($principal, $years, $months, $interest_rate, $compound, $frequency, $down);
```

Comment: thanks for this solution, its really help full, i need littile guid :-http://www.calcul-de-pret.com/CanadianCalculator/CalcAmort.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of compounding monthly, **compound the mortgage every 6 months.**

Canadian mortgages are compounded every 6 months not monthly.

> With the exception of variable rate mortgages, all mortgages are compounded semi-annually, by law. Therefore, if you are quoted a rate of 6% on a mortgage, the mortgage will actually have an effective annual rate of 6.09%, based on 3% semi-annually. However, you make your interest payments monthly, so your mortgage lender needs to use a monthly rate based on an annual rate that is less than 6%. Why? Because this rate will get compounded monthly. Therefore, we need to find the rate that compounded monthly, results in an effective annual rate of 6.09%. Mathematically, this would be:

(1+rM)12-1 = 0.0609

rM = (1.0609)1/12

rM = 0.493862…%

Source: http://www.yorku.ca/amarshal/mortgage.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is ok - se this mortgage calculator : http://aprc.eu/index.php?page=APR-loan-calculator

The difference of your result and cited Bank calcultor stems from different assumptions. The formula you use is for monthly payments **at the end** of the month. If the payments are made **at the beginning** of the month, then iterests are lower, hence payment may be lower too.